# No luck dual booting

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7

I solved one problem only to get a follow-up problem.

I have Win 7 and I tried loading 32-bit Ubuntu 11 on the system.  It kept failing.  I figured out due to another post here that it was because my 3TB drive was too much for it.  After repartitioning the HD my friend and I managed to load it onto the system, but it was buggy when it came to updates, so I tried upgrading to Ubuntu 12 (32 bit), but I was still having the too many bits problem.

Plus now it seems like something is wrong with loading anything.  Both Win 7 and Ubuntu are there, but neither will load.  I get a mostly blank screen with the words:

**error:  no such device: 3a0d062c-5f69-4635-9c79-3814c7d5bbed

grub rescue>**

(with what appears to be a command prompt)

I loaded U12, 64 bit version, in the hopes it would repair the boot issue.  Everything appeared to install much more smoothly this time and update nicely, but there was no luck in the boot department.  Again, all the data is there, but I'm still getting the black screen when I boot up.  I've also tried the repair function in Win 7 with the install disk and no love.  I can run from a liveCD, but that's still not getting me Win 7 or an installed version of Ubuntu.

I have confirmed both OS are there.  Whatever prompts them to actually start seems to be the missing element.

Thank you in advance.

---

I've tried the terminal commands mentioned below.  I get to the third command and:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdb3 /mnt ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo    mount ~bind/ dev/mnt/dev mount: mount point dev/mnt/dev does not    exist 

...

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdb3 /mnt mount: /dev/sdb3    already mounted or /mnt busy mount: according to mtab, /dev/sdb3 is    already mounted on /mnt 

...

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount ~bind dev    /mnt/sdb3 Usage: mount -V                 : print version

...

 ubuntu@ubuntu:~$    sudo mount --bind/proc/mnt/sdb3 mount: unrecognized option    '--bind/proc/mnt/sdb3' Usage: mount -V                 : print    version

...

 ubuntu@ubuntu:~$    sudo mount --bind/proc /mnt/proc mount: unrecognized option    '--bind/proc' Usage: mount -V                 : print version

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Boot from Ubuntu Live CD.

Open the Terminal.

Mount the partition your Ubuntu Installation is on. If you are not sure which it is, launch gparted (included in the Live CD) if not then install it via software centre and find out. It is Usually a EXT4 Partition. Replace the XY with the drive letter, and partition number.ex: sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt. Then bind the directories, you need, like so:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt

sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev

sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
```

Now we jump into that using chroot.

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

Now to install, check, and update grub you only need to add the partition letter (usually 'a') to replace X  ex: grub-install /dev/sda, grub-install –recheck /dev/sda

```
grub-install /dev/sdX

grub-install --recheck /dev/sdX

update-grub
```

Now you can exit you mounted hard disk,

```
exit

sudo umount /mnt/dev

sudo umount /mnt/proc

sudo umount /mnt
```

Now restart and in terminal

```
sudo update-grub
```

[Source >> How to Repair/Restore/Reinstall Grub 2 with a Ubuntu Live CD](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repairrestorereinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd/)

Comment: I got a little further.  TY.  But I get stuck at the 3rd command.

Comment: Posted below is the terminal screen.

Comment: Well then do a fresh install of ubuntu , if windows is not detected , then on first run of Ubuntu , run this

sudo update-grub

This should solve the problem, or if it doesn't use Boot-Customizer  to make windows detectable.


Thanks for trying though.

Comment: Okay, problem solved.  I am reporting on how:  I followed the instructions here:  http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/when-i-boot-i-get-the-following-msg-error-no-such/6b2a2d89-9e9c-4fcb-89bb-7cad29046fbb

Comment: So now, yes, it was a Windows problem.  Though now, it only boots Windows.  I had tried the fresh install before that, but since it wasn't linux;s problem, it did nothing.  I think I know why though, which is that I have Windows on one HD and Ubuntu on the other and I now need to tell my BIOS which one to talk to first.  Thank you so much for your patience and - case closed!

Comment: @ GrayArcadian - Please post your solution as an answer and accept it as answer. It will be more helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

If not for Boot loader problem ,it seems Windows 32 Bit installation is the problem.

Try this 
[Installer Only Recognizes 801GB of a 3TB RAID1 Array](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127182/installer-only-recognizes-801gb-of-a-3tb-raid1-array)

[Trouble creating 3TB ext4 partition due to msdos-partition-table-imposed error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84538/trouble-creating-3tb-ext4-partition-due-to-msdos-partition-table-imposed-error)

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1908753

Or for more info

http://www.anandtech.com/show/3981/western-digital-caviar-green-3tb-and-my-book-essential-3tb-drives-reviewed/2

Comment: Can I have a little more information on "windows 32 bit is the problem?"  I am in way over my head here, tech-wise.  Most of those articles I read before this.  This how I discovered 32-bit + 3tb HD = bad, but beyond that it does not look like these articles are addressing my current problem, though I may be wrong.