# Failed to install GRUB2 on a RAID0 SSD

Tags: boot, grub2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install GRUB on a RAID system installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43036/how-do-i-install-grub-on-a-raid-system-installation)

I installed Ubuntu successfully except the last step.
I cannot install GRUB2 on my disk.

My disk is a Rai0-SSD.
All disks are SSD, totally 512G.

That's the detail
http://paste.ubuntu.com/1285121/