# Problem reinstall GRUB2

Tags: grub2, 12.10, dist-upgrade

I tried to upgrade from 12.04 -> 12.10.  The install seemed to go well but upon reboot, I get the grub recovery console.

I tried to reinstall using the boot-repair [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

which usually works a treat.  However this time it says it is scanning my HDD and never recovers.

When I try to reinstall grub from the liveDVD using the old

```
    grub-install <dir> <dev> --recheck --debug &> gruboutput.txt
```

I get this

[Pastebin link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1301691/)

I think it should be installing to dev/mapper/isw_gbaaebhfe_Volume0 even when I made  --> dev/mapper/isw_gbaaebhfe_Volume3

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please run `Boot-Repair --> Recommended Repair` , then indicate the new URL that will appear. Reboot and tell us what you observe.

Comment: It doesn't get that far. When it starts it says its scanning my hardware and doesn't ever get any further.

Answer (score 1):

Create Boot-Repair-Disk would be better option. You can download it [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/).

Comment: okay I'll give that a try when I get home.  Thanks

Comment: It will 100% work.

Comment: It did not work.  It doesn't have raid drivers.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand.  How do I do that?

Comment: check out this http://askubuntu.com/questions/43036/how-do-i-install-grub-on-a-raid-system-installation for raid

Answer (score 1):

IF you fail to see the Grub:- Insert a Ubuntu 12.10 Live-CD/DVD and run the following commands:

`$sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt` # XY is the drive, eg. sda or sda1

`$sudo chroot /mnt`

`$sudo grub-install /dev/sdX` #X is drive number

`$sudo update-grub` # Note that you just need to enter the 'drive' identifier here, not the partition!

Reboot and take out the LiveDVD. Lemme know if it doesn't work as intended.

Comment: This is not working in Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: In that case, he'd have to use a Boot Repair Disk.

Comment: I didn't explicitly say so in my question - I have now edited - but this is what I did using the liveDVD.  @K.K Patel.  is this a known bug?

Comment: Yes, it is Bug with Grub but not more known.

Comment: One tip that just 'might' work: Most OSes are known to be problematic with a specific system. Try installing on you HDD y connecting it to another machine. For eg, my laptop always fails to install FreeBSD (so does all my friends' who use same system). But, it works fine when I install it on my HDD by plugging it into my desktop! Try it.

Answer (score 1):

you can also have ultimate boot cd on hand run super grub it will allow you to boot the os then run **sudo update-grub** from the os