# Cannot boot Windows 7 or boot from any bootable media

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, windows-7, boot-failure, bootloader

I deleted the Ubuntu partition via Windows 7. I rebooted the machine and I it drops to a  `Grub rescue` prompt.

I tried to boot from Ubuntu live DVD, USB and Windows 7 Repair CD, but didn't succeed. I also tried to changed the boot sequence on the BIOS to boot from CD/DVD, but got the same.

I also updated the BIOS to the latest thinking it might be a BIOS issue but got the same.
Machine comes up to `grub rescue` prompt.

Comment: See  this question the solution will be same.http://askubuntu.com/questions/205546/problem-reinstall-grub2/205559#205559

Comment: Please indicate your [Boot-Info URL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info).

Answer (score 2):

Likely what has happened is that GRUB is trying to find the formatted partition, but cannot. When this happens (I have personally experienced this) GRUB goes into rescue mode.

If it is possible to boot from a "Live CD" then you should boot so (into Ubuntu) and follow the following tutorial: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Yes, it does say it is for after installing Windows, but it serves this purpose perfectly as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Brenneman...but i issue at this point is i cant boot from cd/dvd/usb. i checked the bios setting they are correct and the dvd i am using is bootable. but everytime i reboot my laptop. it does NOT boot from cd.dvd.usb. it goes to grub rescue promt. any thoughts

Comment: @saltpetre What BIOS are you running? Also, have you tried the dvd on a different computer?