# I think I messed up GRUB (RAID installation)

Tags: boot, grub2, raid

Today I was doing a `apt-get dist-upgrade`, and a popup showed up, "Do you want to follow without installing grub?" or something like that, and I wrongly pressed YES, So, I have done a `apt-get install grub` and `grub-install /dev/sda`, and I used `grub-emu` to test if it worked, but...

```
error: no such device: a9ef93bc-2be5-465b-86b5-9f631349c3be.
error: can't find command 'linux'.    
error: can't find command 'initrd'.
Press any key to continue...
```

BootInfo (From boot-repair): http://paste2.org/AUWMhpOj

I tried `boot-repair`, but it froze just after installing grub using `apt-get`.

I haven't rebooted yet, I fear the worst...
I need to mention my root consists of 2 disks with RAID (10gb each).

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2216265

Comment: The most useful links I can come up with are these: http://askubuntu.com/q/43036/40581 http://askubuntu.com/q/88384/40581 Remember to use the md set where it reads sda, and also remember to boot the live media correctly, some parts in boot-info say you have UEFI some that you have MBR. You would have to install mdadm in the live system and GRUB EFI (`grub-efi-amd64-bin`). As you almost found out: emu does not understand your setup and doesn't find the modules on the drive. Good luck. (I don't have time and experience to setup mdadm in a VM currently.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so there was no **actual** problem in GRUB, the warnings seemingly appeared because `grub-emu` was trying to check GRUB's entire start routine but it wasn't able to find a real OS to start.

*"Don't panic."* — Douglas Adams

Comment: Thanks for coming back and aswering this dude, I've been freaking out about this for like 30 minutes!