# Need help installing Ubuntu 18.04 onto a Raid 0 of two disks

Tags: grub2, raid

First a disclaimer, this is being done on a KVM/Qemu vm before I attempt with a live system.  Same setup worked fine with Fedora.  When trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 I get the a fatal error.  Start off by manually setting up partitions since the installer does not give the option to set up raid.

ls /dev/vd*
/dev/vda1
/dev/vdb1

mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=0 --raid-devices=2 /dev/vda1 /dev/vdb1

Then I start the installer.  When it gets to the point of installing grub it give me a fatal error cannot install grub on /dev/vda

I got the same error when using the mini.iso netboot installer for Ubuntu 18.04

-Bryan

Comment: Possible:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/43036/how-do-i-install-grub-on-a-raid-system-installation specifically the second answer.  You might have to see during the installation if it allows you to choose which drive and it might be one that starts with `/dev/mapper` .

Comment: Yes, I can choose the partition to install to during installation, in this case /dev/md0 which I format and set to root.  It is during the grub install however that it fails.  Again this works fine with Fedora.

Answer (score 1):

After fiddling around with it all night I discovered the problem.  Ubuntu doesn't agree with the virtio driver.  After switching the Qemu driver to SATA it worked fine :)

Comment: can you explain better what did you did? (I mean step by step) Thank you!!!